# matching everything between two words, while last word being matched is optional

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to capture everything between 'one' and 'four', the 'four' being optional. We don't know what's between 'one' and 'four'. I tried matching it, but not getting the right result. What am I doing wrong?

```
$text = "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten";
preg_match("~one( .+)(four)?~i", $text, $match);

print_r($match);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => one two three four five six seven eight nine ten [1] => two three four five six seven eight nine ten )
```

**Need Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => one two three four five six seven eight nine ten [1] => two three [3] => four)
```

PS: Yes, the 'four' needs to be optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to use alternation operator.

```
one(( .+)(four).*|.*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pA4dN6/2)

Comment: no, `( .+)(four).*|.*` , `or` ie, `|` applies to `( .+)(four).*` and `.*`

Comment: Ah...this regex also matches just the word 'one';

Comment: don't want that, then try `one(( .+)(four).*|.+)`

Answer (score 0):

By default repeat operators (like "?", "*", "+" or {n,m}) are greedy - they wil try to match as much symbols as they can. You can read more on this behalf here: [What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

To make them not greedy add "?" after them. Like this:
"~one( .+?)(four)?~i"

Comment: This is the result after I followed your advice: Array ( [0] => one t [1] => t )

Comment: 1) My solution is wrong in terms of  it is not going to work if there is no word "four" - group will be empty.
2) Problem with original regex is in greed "+" operator.
3) I think you should use Avinash Raj's solution. As it cover all cases. The only thing you should be aware - if there is several words "four" - if will match until last one, not first. Hope that's what you want.